# Showing a certain sequence forms an orthogonal basis in $L^2$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

We want to show that sequence

($\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$,$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sin(x)$,$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\cos(x)$,
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sin(2x)$,$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\cos(2x)$, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sin(3x)$,$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\cos(3x)$,...)

is complete orthonormal sequence in $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$. So first we would need to show the sequence is orthonormal. Going over a few cases, it is easy to show for $f,g \in L^2(-\pi,\pi)$ that $(f,f) = 1$ and $(f,g) = 0$ with respect to the $L^2$ norm. To show this orthonormal sequence is complete by definition we need to show $0 \in L^2(-\pi,\pi)$ is the only element orthogonal to each term in the sequence. We also know that Fourier sequence $(f_k(y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{iky})_{-\infty}^\infty$ is complete orthonormal sequence in $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$, where $y \in (-\pi,\pi)$. The Fourier sequence looks similar to the given sequence, maybe we could do some manipulations to it and show the given sequence is complete?

Comment: You can use the completeness of the known complex basis by showing that $\{\frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}}, \frac 1{\sqrt\pi}\sin x, \frac 1{\sqrt\pi}\cos x, \ldots, \frac 1{\sqrt\pi}\sin(nx), \frac 1{\sqrt\pi}\cos(nx)\}$ and $\{\frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}}, \frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{ix}, \frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-ix}, \ldots, \frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{inx}, \frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-inx} \}$ span the same space for all $n$.

Comment: That is definitely one approach, since we already know the second sequence you wrote is complete, then the closure of the linear span is $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$, but is there a easy way to show this is also true for the sequence we are trying to show is complete? I was thinking of maybe taking the approach that if $f \in L^2(-\pi,\pi)$ is orthogonal to each function in the first sequence you wrote, then somehow showing that implies it also has to be orthogonal to the second sequence you wrote, from there we could conclude f = 0 almost everywhere on $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$ since second sequence complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: write each of your "new" orthonormal functions as a linear combination of your known complete sequence.  I.e. $\cos(x)=(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})/2$. Then use completeness of $\{e^{ikx/}\sqrt{2\pi}\}$.

Comment: Hey, I just realized this as well, thanks for confirming.